# What algorithms / optimisations are there for calculating a conditional subset of elements from an array?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, data-structures, c++builder

My program often deals with large quantities of data, and one particular component of it creates a subset of that data, based on a condition.  You could view this as, having the string,

```
10457038005502
```

the problem is to return the first five (say) non-0 elements, that is to return:

```
14573
```

In actual fact, each element of this string is a large data structure containing a sizeable amount of data, the entire dataset often being several gigabytes in size and comprising tens of thousands of elements, *and* to figure out if the element should be included (is not a '0') each element needs to be processed.  I've phrased it as I have above both to try to explain it clearly, and also to try to keep this focused on algorithms or techniques, not our specific implementation and data.

- **Edit:** Thanks to those who have replied so far.  All suggestions
  revolve around multithreading, which
  I agree is a good approach (and we do
  have a threaded task framework this
  would fit into.)  I was hoping that
  the problem itself can be treated as
  an algorithmic problem - I suspect,
  though I don't know, that it's a
  general sort of problem applicable to
  searching through all sorts of data. 
  In this light, an awesome reply would
  be "Schwarzenegger et al proposed
  algorithm X for this in 1995, google
  this term."

Our current approach is a single-threaded linear search from the first point we already know in the input data set, along the array, calculating if an element needs to be kept or not and building the results as we go.  Often the requested data subset is not at the beginning - using the string example, you might need to know, say, elements 8-15 (if 15 exist, which you might not know until you've hit the end of the input data.)  Of course, we don't know what element 8 of the output dataset is in the input dataset until we've processed that far from the beginning.

**How else should we solve this problem?**

I am seeking input on any completely different approaches or algorithms to solve this kind of problem.

- What other approaches are there to this problem, ie quickly getting an arbitrary subset?
- Knowing the current solution is computation-bound because of the amount of processing per element, or rather, because it requires each element to be generated in order to examine it to see if it's a '0', what algorithms or approaches might you suggest to tackle the problem?  Is there any way to minimise the work the program does?

If it affects specific libraries or tools, we are using C++ (not managed; we use [Embarcadero C++ Builder 2010](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder).)  For example, we can't use LINQ which, without having used it, I think could be a useful tool / language feature for this sort of problem.  However, we can of course implement any algorithmic solutions that you might normally implement with less work in another environment.

Comment: Is your only problem finding the first *k* non-zero elements in your string (or equivalent vector of data structures), or do you have other problems to solve? Also, how do you check if a data structure is `0`? Do you have a function which you apply to each element which returns whether it's a `0`?

Comment: It is any subset, ie elements k-k+100, not necessarily from element 0.  There is a method which we run on each data structure which returns if it is 0 or not, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each computation can be carried independently of others (i.e., that the results for an item do not depend on the results from a previous item) the obvious first step would be to use multithreading to carry out the computations in parallel.

Comment: For the input data, each element's value is generally standalone.  How it's generated can vary wildly, but assuming an element exists, it's standalone.  For the output data, it does seem that the inclusion of an item (given you request a specific indexed subset) depends on processing each of the previous input data items.  

Re multithreading, do you mean something like partitioning the input data and processing each partition in threads or as task object to get a list of 0/non-0 elements, and then re-assembling?

Comment: Yes -- the idea would be that if (for example) you're asked for the first 5 non-zero items, that you read the first five inputs, and then spin up five threads to process those five items in parallel. I can see where inclusion of a non-zero item might depend on how many were found previously, but if you're asked for N, then you can process at least the first N in parallel, and be sure any positive results will be used. Yes, when you have your results, you then re-assemble them back into original order.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick read of your question I suppose that you might want to implement some sort of master-worker parallelisation.  Have one thread (or process, you choose) read the first N entries, start up N threads(or processes) and pass one task to each.  Each thread then works independently and reports back to the master upon completion (success or failure).  Master then determines whether more tasks need to be created and passed to workers.

The main potential problem with this is probably ensuring good load-balancing across workers, and ensuring that the master thread is not too much of a bottleneck.

OpenMP 3.0 supports this type of task parallelism and has a fairly gentle learning curve.

Comment: OpenMP unfortunately doesn't work with C++ Builder (see http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-compilers/ .)  Thanks for the reply / algorithm/approach suggestion though!